# Why is my form not returning an alert when password does not match the confirm password field Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm new to JS, and I'm trying to make this form prevent submission if password does not match the confirm password field. However, when I enter in 2 different passwords, I don't get an alert like I've coded in the script below. Any thoughts? For reference, the form was built w/ bootstrap.

```
   <form class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="text" id="fullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
              <label for="fullName">Full name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
              <label for="inputEmail">Work email</label>
            </div>
            

            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
              <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-label-group">
              <input type="password" id="inputConfirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
              <label for="inputConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" id ="register-btn" type="submit">Register</button>
            <hr class="my-4">
            <div class="registration-login">
            <p class="already-have__account">Already have an account?</p><a href="log-in.html">&nbsp;Login</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="registration__section">
    <h2>Innovative supply chain teams use Rumi to manage scalable and sustainable packaging.
    </h2>
</div>

<script>
  var form = document.getElementById('form-signin');
  form.onsubmit = function() {

    if (inputPassword.value !== inputConfirmPassword.value) {
      alert("Your passwords don't match");
      return false;
    }

    else {
      return true;
    }

  }
```

Comment: I am sure there is an error message in your developer console. A class is not an id.

Comment: Returning false prevents the form submission only when used in an inline code. You've to prevent the default action in other handlers. You should also not rely on IDs creating global variables, they could have been overridden. Always use `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: @Teemu wrong.........

Comment: @epascarello What's wrong? Everything I said is correct, though it's not fixing OP's actual issue here.

Comment: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null is what it says, I tried wrapping the function in window.onload = function(), but still nothing

Comment: @ZaidShahatit That error means it can not find the element. It can not find the element because you are looking for an id that does not exist.

Comment: @epascarello but in the HTML above, the <form class="form-signin">, and in the JS I used:  var form = document.getElementById('form-signin');

Comment: @Teemu returning false/true works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ZaidShahatit And you use getElementById.... how is that supposed to find a class?

Comment: @epascarello sorry, I'm slowly learning Javascript. Then should I change the HTML to <form ID="form-signin"> ? EDIT - just switched it, and it worked. Bless you

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor mistake.

You are using get getElementById.

```
 var form = document.getElementById('form-signin');
```

There is no id with 'form-signin',

```
<form class="form-signin">
```

Rename the class to id.

```
<form id="form-signin">
```

[Check out this](https://jsfiddle.net/r2ojw4La/4/) (JSFiddle). It's working here.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. What dictates whether you should be using ID or class? For instance, on my ecommerce website (Shopify), everything is labelled by class. But in this project, I've noticed ID used several times.

Comment: You can get element with class also  by this document.getElementsByClassName("example"); Main difference is that Id is unique, where as class is not unique.